# DateTime from TickCount?

Tags: c#, datetime

I am capturing some events in a C# program that come back with the timestamp as a system tickcount (milliseconds since start time).

Knowing, based on other questions I've seen, that I can get the same number from `System.Environment.TickCount` property (or something else), how can I infer the DateTime object that corresponds to the TickCount I received?

Comment: You don't know how often and how long the machine has been hibernating.

Comment: @HansPassant, good point, especially nowadays with all the virtualization...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, without more information (and even then it can be ambiguous). [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) returns:

> A 32-bit signed integer containing the amount of time in milliseconds that has passed since the last time the computer was started.

... so unless you can find out the time the computer was started from somewhere, you're out of luck. There may well be registry entries or system calls you can make to find out the last boot time, but I don't know them off the top of my head. Of course, you can get an *approximate* value by taking `Environment.TickCount` yourself and `DateTime.UtcNow` as soon after (or before) that as possible, and finding the difference between the two:

```
public static DateTime UnreliableDateTimeFromTickCount(int tickCount)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime boot = now - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount);
    return boot + TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(tickCount);
}
```

However, even *with* that, the value will cycle round every 24.9 days, so if the computer has been on for longer than that, the count is ambiguous.

I'd suggest avoiding using `Environment.TickCount` if possible, basically - is this under your control at all?

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted to know. I thought about this option but as you mentioned, it could be highly unreliable. Is it for sure that there is no way to reliable get it? (As for your question, yes, this is under my control, and I can completely avoid doing any of this, but wanted to be sure if it could be done and how.)

Comment: @Alpha: Well how could it ever be reliable in the case where the system's been up for more than 24.9 days? To be honest, the slight inaccuracy due to the time between taking `UtcNow` and `Environment.TickCount` is probably very small - a few milliseconds at most. It's the ambiguity which is the bigger problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet This is very interesting. What if I had no control over that, e.g. a piece of hardware providing message timestamps as millis from last boot? Given that GetTickCount64 could be used to avoid TickCount cycle, which is the best way (in terms of time precision) to place the timestamp on an absolute scale?

Comment: @Adhara: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. If your only input is "time since last boot" then you can't get an absolute time.

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for your reply, but I do not get it. I'm facing a situation which is similar to the one described by the OP. I'm receiving messages from a driver and each message has a timestamp that represents milliseconds from boot time. My idea was: if I had boot time, then adding those timestamps would give me the absolute time (I mean, a date). One way to accomplish this would be using your function above with which I could retrieve the approximate boot time.

Comment: @Adhara: "Adding those timestamps" - to what? To each other? If *nothing* is giving you an absolute time, then it's not going to help you. My method only helps because `DateTime.UtcNow` is available. If you don't have that, please ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: Ok, sorry for my poor English then.Step one: create a class OffsetFromBootToAbsoluteDateTime and in the constructor execute first 2 lines in your UnreliableDateTimeFromTickCount. Store boot in a private m_boot field which then contains the absolute boot time. Then, each time a new timestamp arrives, call OffsetFromBootToAbsoluteDateTime.ToAbsolute(millis) that simply sums millis to the m_boot time (as you do at line 3 of your example). I'm just facing the issue of translating _millis from boot time_ into absolute time on a window machine given that millis from boot time is not under my control

Comment: @Adhara: As per my previous comment, please ask a new question. Comment threads on SO are not for "I'm in a similar but not quite the same situation".

Comment: @JonSkeet the situation is the same. I just cannot explain myself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @JonSkeet wouldn't `ulong GetTickCount64()` (Kernel32.lib) be good for up to 49 days?

Comment: @JohnB: Unless it wraps round for some reason, that should be good for *much* longer than that - it's 64 bits rather than 32. But personally I'd need a *really* good reason to tie my code to Windows.

Comment: @JonSkeet: It seems like he doesn't want TickCount and would prefer to have `DateTime` or `TimeSpan` instead.  I posted an answer below, but as it uses WMI it is also tied to Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I recognize that this is a very old question, but since it was the first hit from Google when I was searching, I felt others may land here.
All of the points in @JonSkeet's answer are valid and be sure to read them and fully understand where it applies to you.  For my specific situation, I knew that the tick count value I needed to convert would be within the last few days, however there was a risk that the value captured was before TickCount overflowed, and the conversion would occur after.  Below is the method I wrote which should handle the case of TickCount overflowing and will convert the given tick count into a DateTime, **as long as it is within the last 49 days.**

To elaborate a little more on how Environment.TickCount works: When the computer turns on, it starts at 0 and increments each millisecond.  After 24.9 days from booting, the capacity of a Int32 is reached and TickCount rolls over from Int32.MaxValue to Int32.MinValue.  After the initial wrap, it will continue to overflow every 49.7 days.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts the given tick count into a DateTime. Since TickCount rolls over after 24.9 days, 
/// then every 49.7 days, it is assumed that the given tickCount occurrs in the past and is 
/// within the last 49.7 days.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tickCount">A tick count that has occurred in the past 49.7 days</param>
/// <returns>The DateTime the given tick count occurred</returns>
private DateTime ConvertTickToDateTime(int tickCount)
{
    // Get a reference point for the current time
    int nowTick = Environment.TickCount;
    DateTime currTime = DateTime.Now;
    Int64 mSecElapsed = 0;

    // Check for overflow condition
    if( tickCount < nowTick) // Then no overflow has occurred since the recorded tick
    {
        // MIN|--------------TC---------------0------------Now-------------|MAX
        mSecElapsed = nowTick - tickCount;
    }
    else // tickCount >= currTick; Some overflow has occurred since the recorded tick
    {
        // MIN|--------------Now---------------0------------TC-------------|MAX
        mSecElapsed = Convert.ToInt64((int.MaxValue - tickCount) + (nowTick + Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(int.MinValue))));   // Time BEFORE overflow + time since the overflow
    }

    DateTime tickCountAsDateTime = currTime - TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(mSecElapsed);
    return tickCountAsDateTime;        
}
```

To test the method, I used the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test Start Time: {0}", DateTime.Now);

    // 10 seconds ago
    int tc0 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 10 seconds ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc0));

    // 10 minutes ago
    int tc1 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 10 minutes ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc1));

    // 10 hours ago
    int tc2 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromHours(10));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 10 hours ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc2));

    // 1 Day ago
    int tc3 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromDays(1));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 1 Day ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc3));

    // 10 Day ago
    int tc4 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromDays(10));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 10 Days ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc4));

    // 30 Day ago
    int tc5 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromDays(30));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 30 Days ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc5));

    // 48 Day ago
    int tc6 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromDays(48));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect 48 Days ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc6));

    // 50 Day ago (Should read as a more recent time because of the Environment.TickCount wrapping limit - within a day or two)
    int tc7 = CalculateTC(TimeSpan.FromDays(50));
    Console.WriteLine("Expect to not see 50 Days ago: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc7));

    // 10 Seconds ahead (Should read as a very old date - around 50 days ago)
    int tc8 = Convert.ToInt32(Environment.TickCount + TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10).TotalMilliseconds);
    Console.WriteLine("Expect to not see 10 seconds from now: {0}", ConvertTickToDateTime(tc8));    
}


private static int CalculateTC(TimeSpan timespan)
{
    int nowTick = Environment.TickCount;
    double mSecToGoBack = timespan.TotalMilliseconds;

    int tc;

    if (Math.Abs(nowTick - int.MinValue) >= mSecToGoBack) // Then we don't have to deal with an overflow
    {
        tc = Convert.ToInt32(nowTick - mSecToGoBack);
    }
    else // Deal with the overflow wrapping
    {
        double remainingTime = nowTick + Math.Abs(Convert.ToDouble(int.MinValue));
        remainingTime = mSecToGoBack - remainingTime;

        tc = Convert.ToInt32(int.MaxValue - remainingTime);
    }
    return tc;
}
```

The following is the output from the test application:

```
Test Start Time: 5/3/2019 4:30:05 PM
Expect 10 seconds ago: 5/3/2019 4:29:55 PM
Expect 10 minutes ago: 5/3/2019 4:20:05 PM
Expect 10 hours ago: 5/3/2019 6:30:05 AM
Expect 1 Day ago: 5/2/2019 4:30:05 PM
Expect 10 Days ago: 4/23/2019 4:30:05 PM
Expect 30 Days ago: 4/3/2019 4:30:05 PM
Expect 48 Days ago: 3/16/2019 4:30:05 PM
Expect to not see 50 Days ago: 5/3/2019 9:32:53 AM
Expect to not see 10 seconds from now: 3/14/2019 11:27:28 PM
```

I hope this helps someone who may be in a similar situation as me.

Comment: would you still need to do the rollover calculation if you used `ulong GetTickCount64()` (Kernel32.lib) instead of `Environment.TickCount`?

Comment: Off hand I don't see a reason you couldn't pull in GetTickCount64 and avoid the rollover issue.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a tick-count as `int`

It seems like you would prefer different datatypes:

- system up-time as `TimeSpan`
- system start-time as `DateTime`

*(However I am not 100% sure based on the wording of your question)*

Below is a code example that uses [Windows Management Instrumentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmi-start-page) to get those properties.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;
using System.Linq;

namespace MachineTimeStamps
{
    class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Print the system Uptime and Last Bootup Time (using Win32_OperatingSystem LocalDateTime & LastBootUpTime properties).
        /// </summary>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var uptime = GetSystemUptime("COMPUTER_NAME");

            if (!uptime.HasValue)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("GetSystemUptime() response was null.");
            }

            var lastBootUpTime = GetSystemLastBootUpTime("COMPUTER_NAME");

            if (!lastBootUpTime.HasValue)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("GetSystemLastBootUpTime() response was null.");
            }

            Console.WriteLine($"Uptime: {uptime}");
            Console.WriteLine($"BootupTime: {lastBootUpTime}");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the duration (TimeSpan) since the system was last started.
        /// Note: can be used on a local or a remote machine.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="computerName">Name of computer on network to retrieve uptime for</param>
        /// <returns>WMI Win32_OperatingSystem LocalDateTime - LastBootUpTime</returns>
        private static TimeSpan? GetSystemUptime(string computerName)
        {
            string namespaceName = @"root\cimv2";
            string queryDialect = "WQL";

            DComSessionOptions SessionOptions = new DComSessionOptions();
            SessionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationType.Impersonate;

            CimSession session = CimSession.Create(computerName, SessionOptions);

            string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
            var cimInstances = session.QueryInstances(namespaceName, queryDialect, query);

            if (cimInstances.Any())
            {
                var cimInstance = cimInstances.First();
                var lastBootUpTime = Convert.ToDateTime(cimInstance.CimInstanceProperties["LastBootUpTime"].Value);
                var localDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(cimInstance.CimInstanceProperties["LocalDateTime"].Value);

                var uptime = localDateTime - lastBootUpTime;
                return uptime;
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Retrieves the last boot up time from a system.
        /// Note: can be used on a local or a remote machine.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="computerName">Name of computer on network to retrieve last bootup time from</param>
        /// <returns>WMI Win32_OperatingSystem LastBootUpTime</returns>
        private static DateTime? GetSystemLastBootUpTime(string computerName)
        {
            string namespaceName = @"root\cimv2";
            string queryDialect = "WQL";

            DComSessionOptions SessionOptions = new DComSessionOptions();
            SessionOptions.Impersonation = ImpersonationType.Impersonate;

            CimSession session = CimSession.Create(computerName, SessionOptions);

            string query = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
            var cimInstances = session.QueryInstances(namespaceName, queryDialect, query);

            if (cimInstances.Any())
            {
                var lastBootUpTime = Convert.ToDateTime(cimInstances.First().CimInstanceProperties["LastBootUpTime"].Value);
                return lastBootUpTime;
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I seemed to get the wrong results from Jerren's solution; this might be a fudge/incorrect - where the complexity of overflows is concerned, but this got me close to the right results for my tests, an attempt at approximating the result:

```
    // TimeSpan result

    var approxUpTime = TryApproximateUpTime();

    private static TimeSpan? TryApproximateUpTime()
    {
        TimeSpan? retVal;

        var envTickCountInMs =
            Environment.TickCount;

        try
        {
            retVal = 
                envTickCountInMs > 0
                    ?
                        new DateTime()
                            .AddMilliseconds(Environment.TickCount) -
                                DateTime.MinValue
                    :
                        new TimeSpan(
                            new DateTime(
                                ((long)int.MaxValue + (envTickCountInMs & int.MaxValue)) * 10 * 1000).Ticks);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // IGNORE
            retVal = null;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```